# javascript traversing through an object

Tags: javascript, object, loops, traversal

I have an object that is dynamically created. Here's a simple example:

```
global.data {
    children: [
        0: {
            children:  [
                0: {
                   children: value 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

What I want to do is check if the object (global.data) has a property of 'children', grab properties from it, and send that object ('children') back through the loop to see if it has a property of 'children' of it's own. I want it to keep going until there are no more 'children' left to traverse though.

Comment: are you able to post the dump from `JSON.stringify(global.data)`? And more importantly, it looks as though you've got a tree structure, is only the first child being tested, or do you want to traverse across every node in the tree?

Comment: There ware a lot more properties that can be added, so it won't ever be in the same position. I would have to traverse across every node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run a while loop till it reaches to deepest. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPe5R/4/)

```
global = {};
global.data = {
    children: [
         {
            children:  [
                 {
                   children: "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

var obj = global.data;

while( typeof obj == 'object' && typeof obj.children == 'object'){
  obj = obj.children[0];
}
obj = obj.children ? obj.children  : obj;​
 // at this point obj is either undefined or has no children property.
```

Comment: This is working, but is only going one level deep for me. I'm not sure if it is something on my end or not though. Could I bother you to possible make a jsfiddle for me to play around with?

Comment: I made the changes in my code. Format of object you provided is not valid . you dont need to specify index of array while creating an array. I changed it. let me know you face any problem. jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bPe5R/4/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful for data processing once you wrap your head around it. The below example will only return the first value, but can easily be changed to return all matches by changing `abort`.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const input = { children: [{ children: [{ children: 'value' }] }] };

const find = (data) => objectScan(['**(^children$)'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value',
  useArraySelector: false,
  filterFn: ({ value }) => typeof value === 'string'
})(data);

console.log(find(input));
// => value
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)