# Traverse through multi-dimentional object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a multi-dimensional object:

```
var obj = {
    prop: {
        myVal: "blah",
        otherVal: {
             // lots of other properties
        },
    },
};
```

How would one traverse the entire object, without knowing any of the property names or the number of "dimensions" in the object?

There are a couple other questions on SO that are related to the topic:

[Traverse through Javascript object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366104/traverse-through-javascript-object-properties)
[javascript traversing through an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038014/javascript-traversing-through-an-object)

The problem is that both answers are not quite what I am looking for, because:

**a)** The first link only iterates through the first layer in the object.
**b)** The second answer requires you to know the names of the object's keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion:

```
function doSomethingWithAValue(obj, callback) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    if (typeof val !== 'object') {
      callback(val);
    } else {
      doSomethingWithAValue(val, callback);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Object.keys

Comment: @Sukima, do you mean `for...in`? `for...of` is a new ES6 feature.

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) introduced in ES5 is an easy way to get an array of an object keys. Unlike the old standard of [`for…in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) it only returns the properties defined and skips the ones inherited through the prototype. Something that would require yet another if/then branch using `hasOwnProperty()` in the `for…in` style

Comment: Yeah I meant `for…in`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful for data processing once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you'd do a simple iteration in delete safe order:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const obj = { prop: { myVal: 'blah', otherVal: { /* lots of other properties */ } } };

objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ key, value }) => {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
})(obj);
// => [ 'prop', 'otherVal' ] {}
// => [ 'prop', 'myVal' ] blah
// => [ 'prop' ] { myVal: 'blah', otherVal: {} }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)