# How to console.log props of obj and check if prop is func so run this func?

Tags: javascript, object

Execute output to the console of all properties of the object, transferring the child properties to a new line.

If the property is of type Function, do not output to the console, but call the function.

```
let data = {
a: {a: 1,
    b: {a: 3,b: 10},
    c: 14},
b: {f: function () {console.log("this is function");},
    a: "123"}
};

showNodes(data);

function showNodes(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Loop over properties, if it's an object, step into recursively. If not console.log, if a function invoke it.

Comment: try this `console.log(typeof f);`  or `if(typeof f == "function"){ // do something }`

Answer (score 1):

**Loop through Object**

if you want to traverse an object you can do it like this:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  obj[prop] = 'xxx';
}
```

if the object hast multiple dimensions (like in your example) you can do it like this:

```
function doSomethingWithAValue(obj, callback) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    if (typeof val !== 'object') {
      callback(val);
    } else {
      doSomethingWithAValue(val, callback);
    }
  });
}
```

the code is from this SO answer: [Traverse through multi-dimentional object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662068/traverse-through-multi-dimentional-object?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Check if function**

to check if an element is a function you can use typeof.

```
typeof obj[key] === 'function'
```

hope this helps

good luck :)

Comment: Same as comment for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
func: function(){
alert("as")
},
name:{name:"xxx", fun2: function(){
alert('inner')
}}
}

rcv(obj)
function rcv(obj){
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log( typeof obj[key])
      if(typeof obj[key] == 'function') { 
        obj[key]();
      }else if(typeof obj[key] == 'object' && obj[key] && obj[key].constructor !== Array){
        rcv(obj[key])
      }else(
      console.log(obj[key])
      )
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/o2gxgz9r/5923/